# Biblatex: escaped underscore in bib file prints as %5c in bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, urls, biber

My reference manager escapes all underscores in URLs. I thought that was OK until I noticed it prints `%5c` in front of all URL underscores. How can I avoid this while still having the escaped underscores in the bib file? -- I can't change what my reference manager output, unfortunately.

MWE:

test.bib

```
@online{testref,
author = {Some Author},
title = {{Some Title}},
url = {http://www.example.com/some\_file.zip}
}
```

test.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[uniquelist=false,maxcitenames=2,backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
Hello you \citep{testref}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Just type `_` and not `\_`.

Comment: The translation of `\_` into `%5C_` is done by Biber, apparently.

Comment: @egreg I stated that it is my reference software that exports the urls with escaped underscores, not me. Therefore I cannot change it.

Comment: I understand, that's why I added the second comment. I'm afraid it's built in Biber. Let's see if some expert in the internals can find a solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `biber` ability to manipulate the bib entries on the fly with `\DeclareSourcemap`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[uniquelist=false,maxcitenames=2,backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{testref,
author = {Some Author},
title = {{Some Title}},
url = {http://www.example.com/some\_file.zip}
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareSourcemap{
 \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
   \map{
     \step[fieldsource=url,
       match=\regexp{\\_},
       replace=\regexp{_}]
   }
 }
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Hello you \citep{testref}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]